# ASP.NET redirect to a created HTML page, returns error 404

Tags: html, asp.net, redirect

I`m writing a ASP.NET web page to receive a file from the user, using fileUpload, then calling an .exe file to create a HTML based on that file. The HTML contains the file name, file length, etc.

In the program, I used:

```
var proc = Process.Start(path, arg);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

and also:

```
while(!File.Exists("my file path"));
```

I tried using a physical path like "`C:\myWesite\CreateHTML\new.HTML`", also a URL like "`Mywebsite\CreteHTML\new.html`". Both of these should take me to the new page if I type them in the browser.

The file is there when I use `Response.Redirect()`. If not, then the while loop will go on forever and cannot continue to the `Response.Redirect()` command.

The problem is that, after the redirect, it threw a "404 - File or directory not found." error.  But, after I refresh it, the new page works fine even though the URL is the same. So, every time I use the website, I need to refresh in order to see it.

I Also tried `Server.Transer()`, but it didn`t show me the right page.

I used another PC with IIS to work as the server. I develop the webpage on another PC using webmatrix.

Comment: can we see the redirect code?

Comment: wait you're going to let users upload a file that will get processed by an executable on your server? Do you have anything interesting on that server? Can I have the url please?

Comment: You don't need to tell us it's urgent or that you really need help. We assume that because you asked. Also, you don't need to thank us, because we're here to help.

Comment: Hi all, it`s an internal server, nothing special, just parse the user`s file, then create a HTML based on that.

Comment: try server.transfer() ...if you are dealing on the same server...

Comment: The redirect code is like this: Response.Redirect("~/dumpHTML/" + fileName);

Comment: I tried server.transfer(), but it doesn`t show me the page I want.

Comment: If I am getting you correctly... On your 1st response.redirect you get 404 and on refreshing the same page you get the file...so that means you will have to check the existence of the file before you redirect...

Comment: I think that is what he is attempting to do with the while loop, but not sure - I should have been more specific with the code request, not just the redirect but the conditions/logic surrounding the redirect.

Comment: sorry ..I overlooked the above code

Comment: Hi all, the code is like this

var proc = Process.Start(path, arg);
proc.WaitForExit();

while(!File.Exists("my file path"));

Response.Redirect(“my file path”)；  that`s the exact code that I　ｕｓｅ，　ｅｘｃｅｐｔ　ｆｏｒ　ｔｈｅ　ｆｉｌｅ　ｎａｍｅ．

Comment: ｔｈｅ　ｌｏｏｐ　ｔｏ　ｃｈｅｃｋ　ｔｈｅ　ｅｘｉｓｔａｎｃｅ　ｏｆ　ｆｉｌｅ　ｉｓ　ｗｏｒｋｉｎｇ，　ａｌｓｏ　Ｉ　ｔｒｉｅｄ　ｔｏ　ｗａｉｔ　ｆｏｒ　５　ｓｅｃｏｎｄｓ　ｂｅｆｏｒｅ　ｒｅｄｉｒｅｃｔ，　ｂｕｔ　ｓｔｉｌｌ　ｃａｎｎｏｔ　ｇｅｔ　ｔｈｅ　ｐａｇｅ　ｏｎ　ｔｈｅ　１ｓｔ　ｔｒｙ．

Comment: now I wait for 10 seconds using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000) before redirect, and take a look at the physical folder to make sure all the files are there. They are there and still the redirect is not successful. I have to refresh it.

Comment: just try one trick ...do  Server.Transfer(Request.Path); after response.redirect & try to debug if you get the same url..

Comment: I just tried placeHolder, and add a link to the address, and it`s working.

Comment: Server.Transfer take me to a different Path. http://localhost:13466/. This is the default webpage. Is there something wrong with the address I use? but Response.Redirect can take me to the right address, I just need to refresh it.

Comment: hmm now I am lost...might be some caching thing going on which is messing the server.transfer ...

Comment: If the path is wrong, the address shown on the browser should also be wrong, and I cannot get the right page by simply refresh (but this is the most suspicious one). It`s really confusing. I think I will use a hyperlink in the placeholder instead of the redirect. Thanks Scorpio and Shannon!